# Is Apache Ignite suitable for my usecase(load oracle tables to cache,do join between these tables, and reflect changes to oracle data)

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I would ask whether Ignite is suitable for my use case which is:

1. Load all the data of oracle tables to the Ignite cache, and then do various SQL queries(aggregation/join/sub-query) against the data in the cache.
2. When oracle has newly created data or some data are updated, there are some way that these data can be inserted into the cache or update the corresponding entry in the cache
3. When the cache is down, there should be some way to restore the data from oracle?

Not sure Ignite SQLGrid can fit in this use case.

Also, I notice that IgniteRDD is not immutable, is IgniteRDD suitable for this use case? That is, I first load the data in oracle into IgniteRDD,
and make the corresponding changes to IgniteRDD with the newly created/updated data to oracle? But it looks that IgniteRDD doesn't support complicated SQL?( aggregation/join/sub-query)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the basic use cases supported by Ignite.

Data can pre-loaded from Oracle using one of the methods covered in [this documentation section](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading).

If you're planning to update the data in Ignite first and propagate to Oracle after (which is preferred way), then it makes sense to use Oracle as a [`CacheStore`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store) in write-through/read-through mode. Ignite will make sure to sync up data with the persistent layer. Moreover, it'll be straightforward to [pre-load data](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading#ignitecacheloadcache) from Oracle if the cluster is restarted.

Finally, you can take advantage of [GridGain Web Console](https://ignite.apache.org/addons.html#web-console) by connecting to Oracle and [map Oracle's scheme](https://ignite.apache.org/features/rdbmsintegration.html) to Ignite caches configuration and POJO objects.

As I mentioned, it's recommended to make all the updates through Ignite first which will persist them to Oracle. But if Oracle is updated by other applications that are not aware of Ignite you need to update Ignite cluster on your own somehow. Ignite doesn't have any feature that covers this use case. However, this can be easily implemented with GridGain, that is built on top of Ignite, with it's [Oracle Golden Gate Integration](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/syncing-gridgain-memory-computing-cluster-and-database-using-oracle-goldengate).

Once the data is in the Ignite Cluster use [SQL Grid](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-grid) to query and/or update your data. SQL Grid engine is ANSI-99 compliant and doesn't have any limitations.

As for Ignite Shared RDD, it stores data in a distributed Ignite cache. This is why it's mutable which is opposite to Spark native RDDs. Shared RDDs SQL capabilities are absolutely the same - it's just one more API on top of SQL Grid.